# Optimize sql query with group by and aggregate

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, query-optimization

I have a working query as shown below:

```
SELECT TOP 1000
    c.B,
    c.N, 
    c.V,
    c.T,
    SIS = stuff((
                SELECT ', ' +  si.S
                FROM
                    COMP com
                    JOIN CCA cca ON com.Cid = cca.CId
                    JOIN CC cc ON cca.Cid = cc.Cid
                    JOIN SI si ON si.SId = cc.SId
                WHERE
                   com.N=c.N

                FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 2, ''
           )
    FROM
    COMP c
    JOIN CCA cca ON c.Cid = cca.CId
    JOIN CC cc ON cca.Cid = cc.Cid
    JOIN SI si ON si.SId = cc.SId
    where c.N like '%searchstring%'
    and si.Sin like '%searchstring%'
    group by c.B, c.N, c.V, c.T
    order by  c.N desc;
```

It gives correct results. I am doing stuff() to get a comma separated aggregate. The query is slow. Wondering if there is a way to optimize it?

Comment: I think `FOR XML PATH` make your query so slow, If it is possible change your way ;).

Comment: Comparing with LIKE on the WHERE make query slowly too

Answer (score 1):

If you can change your way I suggest you to follow this:

1. Make a stored procedure
2. Make a temp table for storing `COMP.N` and `SIS` and apply `c.N like '%searchstring%'` to it, This will reduce count of calculating `SIS`.
3. Now you can `JOIN` to that temp table on `N`.
4. You can also change `JOIN SI` to `LEFT JOIN SI`, note that when you have a condition over `SI` it will remove `NULL` values.